# How to calculate sum of all input value in text having trailing commas?

Tags: php, input, sum-of-digits

I want to calculate all input values in text which are having or not having trailing commas.
Example I input `2,3,4,5` or `2345` in text box. Its sum should come as `14`, provided user has used or not used `,` in between numbers.

Comment: What if the user wants to input `10,12,14` but inputs it as `101214`? Your method will then sum it to 9 instead of 36

Comment: well any suggesstion would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateStringNumbers($string)
{
    $sum = 0;
    $numbers_array = explode(',',$string);

    if(is_array($numbers_array) && count($numbers_array) > 0 && strpos($string, ',') !== false)
    {
        $sum = array_sum($numbers_array);
    }
    else
    {
        $sum = sum($string);
    }

    echo 'Your Sum is: '.$sum.' cheers';
}


function sum($num) {
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($num); $i++){
        $sum += $num[$i];
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Test Cases:

1 - user input 2345:
   calculateStringNumbers('2345')
Output Your Sum is: 14 cheers

2 - user input 2,3,4,5:
   calculateStringNumbers('2,3,4,5')
Output Your Sum is: 14 cheers

Comment: This solution is wrong. Input 2345 comes out as 2345, not the wanted "14"

Comment: i tested myself bro and than i put the solution.also i haven used any inbuilt functions.if required i will send a working screenshot

Answer (score 0):

My more concise solution would be:

```
$sum = array_sum(preg_split('/[\s,]*/', $input));
```

Answer (score -1):

Lucking after posting my questions , i manage to find a solution by myself..
here it is:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="checkname"/>
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit"/>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['mysubmit']))
{
$test=$_POST['checkname'];

$search_comma=strpos($test,',');    

$testexp=explode(',',$test);

$allsum=implode('',$testexp);

$allsum=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $allsum);

$sum=0;

for($i=0;$i<strlen($allsum);$i++)
{
 $sum=$sum+$allsum[$i];
}
 echo 'Your Sum is:'.$sum;
}
```

User Input 1:1,2,3,4

User Input 2:1234

=================

**Output:** Your Sum is:**10** 
  **cheers :)**

Comment: You have no clue what those functions do, do you?

Comment: iam having clue mr but just asking about the thing that u mentioned.if u dont wanna contribute than its ok no issue..thanks

Comment: There is no answer to your question since you have not covered the edge cases as I wrote in the comments to the question.